# How to display all the names in database firestorefirebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app I have a model which consists of the store name and store image and looks like this:

```
class StoreModel
{
  String? imageofStore;
  String? storeName;

  StoreModel({ this.imageofStore, this.storeName});

  //data from server
  factory StoreModel.fromMap(map)
  {
    return StoreModel(
      imageofStore: map['imageofStore'],
      storeName: map['storeName'],
    );
  }

//  data to server
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return{
      'imageofStore': imageofStore,
      'storeName': storeName,
    };
  }
}
```

and my database for stores looks like this:
[image]

to call the store name I use initstate and setState as such:

```
 class addStore extends StatefulWidget {
  const addStore({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _addStoreState createState() => _addStoreState();
}

class _addStoreState extends State<addStore> {
  
  User ? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  StoreModel storebox = StoreModel();
  
  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("stores")
        .doc("XQjbm665g2a2xAiiydjr")
        .get()
        .then((value){
      this.storebox = StoreModel.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {

      });
    });

  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
     child: Text("${storebox.storeName}"),
    );
  }
}
```

With this, I get the store name of the store with id XQjbm665g2a2xAiiydjr displaying but the thing is I want to get the name of all the stores. I know I need to change the .doc() but im not sure as to what I am to put in it that will start displaying all the names. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By providing a document id, what you're getting is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) which is the data of a particular Document, but when you remove it, you get [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) which is a list of the data of all the documents. So, to read all, you change your code as:

```
List<StoreModel> storesList = [];

FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("stores")
    .get()
    .then((value){
  //Now, this value is of type QuerySnapshot unlike earlier.
  if (value != null && value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
  //If it comes here means the collection is not empty.

  //Because this value is a list of DocumentSnapshot, We've to map it to extract documents.
  //After mapping, returning it as a list and assigning it to storesList
  storesList = value.docs.map((doc) => StoreModel.fromMap(doc.data())).toList();
  setState(() {

  });
  } else {
  //If it comes here means there are no documents in your collection.
  //Notify User there's no data.
  }
});
```

This code will get all the documents your collection have, but, you can limit or filter using `limit` or `where` respectively, just place `.limit(int)` or `.where()` before `.get()`.

Comment: I used storebox.storeName to get the name of the store. What will I have to type to get the name of the first store? 
I tried doing something like storeList.storeName[0] but it doesnt work.

Comment: To get the `storeName` of first or any element, you've to pass the index to the list as storesList[index] and then, access the doc elements like `storesList[index].storeName`, so, for the first element, set the index to 0 as `storesList[0].storeName`.

Answer (score 0):

for model try to convert to json or you can use your either way this is just for example model

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<StoreModel> storeModelFromJson(String str) => List<StoreModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => StoreModel.fromJson(x)));

String storeModelToJson(List<StoreModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class StoreModel {
    StoreModel({
        this.imageofStore,
        this.storeName,
    });

    final String? imageofStore;
    final String? storeName;

    factory StoreModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StoreModel(
        imageofStore: json["imageofStore"] == null ? null : json["imageofStore"]!,
        storeName: json["storeName"] == null ? null : json["storeName"]!,
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "imageofStore": imageofStore == null ? null : imageofStore!,
        "storeName": storeName == null ? null : storeName!,
    };
}
```

try this get all list

```
static Future<List<StoreModel>> getStorelist() async {
  List<dynamic> list = [];
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("stores")
            .get()
            .then((value){
          for(var x in value.docs){
            final Map<String,dynamic> toMap = x.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
          /// Try to print all data first to see if fetching use log to view on terminal
          log(toMap.toString());

       
            list.add(toMap); 
        }
    });
   
    return list.map((e)= > StoreModel.fromJson(e)).toList();  
}
```

as in my case to get only 1 data

```
static getSingleName(String? uid) async {
    final result =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("stores").doc(uid).get();
    final response = result.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return response['storeName'].toString();
  }
```

Comment: this line is giving me error    return list.map((e)= > StoreModel.fromJson(e)).toList(); 
also what command should i write to get the storeName of the first store?

Comment: @newbieperson i edited my answer also the line giving you error did you try the model above?

Comment: @user:10782024
yes i tried the above model. this is the error im getting
A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be returned from the method 'getStorelist' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<StoreModel>>